# Gridgain console load balance

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have Gridgain three node cluster and also running Gridgain web console agent and  web console on all three nodes. It is all hosted on Windows Server.

I would like to load balance My web console. The problem is I don't know how to share user registration database which it stores in a work directory. Can I use external database to store all that information so that my cluster uses the same database?

There is a problem with Web Console Agent as well. How do I share tokens stored in default.properties?

There is no definitive guide on how to create a cluster for web console for high availability.

Can someone please guide me on how can I form a cluster for a Web console sharing its user store and tokens?

Thanks

Comment: You can start several agents and one will take over for another in case of a crash. They could all share the default.properties file via a a commonly mounted directory.

Are you looking to do the same for the web-console UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for multi-cluster support, take a look at documentation:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/multi-cluster-support

If you are looking for agent fault-tolerance: just start several agents. Fisrt agent will process all messages, other will be in the hot-stand-by mode.

If you are looking for connection fault-tolerance between agent and cluster (if cluster node failed that is a connection point for agent, Web Console will loose connection to cluster), just specify several nodes addresses as comma-separated list for "node-uri" parameter (in default.properties or as command-line argument).

For example:

```
node-uri=http://192.168.0.1:8080,http://192.168.0.2:8080;http://192.168.0.3:8080
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a multi-cluster support. And I have web console and its agent running on three different servers Server 1, Server 2, Server 3. Only problem is, how to sync user store of web console between all three servers so that same user doesn't have to register their account on three different servers?

Comment: I think solution with a common network folder + symbolic link to "default.properties" file may work for you.

Comment: How about work/db folder in Web Console? Do I need to share that as well?